# Backpress in fragments is not working properly. How to make this work?

Tags: android

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                                 @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    
            requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                @Override
                public void handleOnBackPressed() {
              
                    this.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });
    
            return mBinding.getRoot();
        }
   @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            //noinspection SwitchStatementWithTooFewBranches
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    callParentMethod();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    private void callParentMethod() {
            requireActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
```

I have use this approach to achieve this. It works twice. In the third press of the back button it get back to the previous fragment. How to prevent the user from getting back to the previous fragment

Answer (score 1):

removed  `this.setEnabled(false);` this line and it worked.

This was setting the activity back press to false.That's why it was not working